# Angular - Pass parameters to transclude component

Tags: angular

I'm trying to understand if the following is possible.
I have a video-uploader component where user can upload one or more videos.
this component has 3 views options 
1. Seperate - in progress videos and uploaded videos are displayed in seperate tables.
2. Combine - All videos are displayed in same table with status
3. UploadOnly - Only  uploaded videos are displayed.

Today the code of video-uploader lookes something likes this

```html
<div class="video-uploader-container">
   <combine-videos-display videos="videos" *ngIf="view = views.combine"> </combine-videos-display>
 <seperate-videos-display videos="videos" *ngIf="view = views.seperate"> </seperate-videos-display>
  <upload-only-videos-display videos="videos" *ngIf="view = views.uploadOnly"> </upload-only-videos-display>
</div>
```

My problem is that the view options can be increased in time, and I really don't want to increase the size of video-uploader with more *ngIf (or ngSwitchCase) and more components.

I thought setting the desiered view component in transclude but my problem is that the videos are being create inside video-uploader-container.
Is there a better way to do this? I don't want video-uploader-container to 
 have to know all the views components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `@ContentChild` to get reference to `TemplateRef` and `ngTemplateOutlet` to pass `videos` as context into `ng-template`:

**video-uploader.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'video-uploader',
  template: `
    <div class="video-uploader-container">
       <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template; context: { $implicit: videos }">
       </ng-container>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ViewUploaderComponent {
  videos: any;

  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) template: TemplateRef<any>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.videos = [
        {
            name: 'video1',
            url: 'test'
        },
        {
            name: 'video2',
            url: 'test'
        }
    ];
  }
}
```

and parent component could look like

```
<video-uploader>
  <ng-template let-videos>
    <combine-videos-display [videos]="videos"></combine-videos-display>
  </ng-template>
</video-uploader>
```

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/drbGAaNnt1hGw4yZAq0j?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It did the job perfectly.
I used this article to understand it a little better:
https://alligator.io/angular/reusable-components-ngtemplateoutlet/